# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch when running django project

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-oauth

Newbie here!
I want to download all the images from a google drive folder and then show them in a basic html.

I am trying to authenticate with google so I can access to the folder, but when I try I always get this error
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl52o.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl52o.png)
What it's weird is that the port changes every time I run the project.
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YQuS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YQuS.png)

The server is running in the port 8000 of localhost.

Here the code for the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Google Drive API scopes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

# Path to credentials file
credentials_path = 'credentials.json'

def index(request):
    # Load existing credentials if available
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    else:
        # If not available, initiate OAuth 2.0 flow
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentials_path, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Save the credentials for future use
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token_file:
            token_file.write(creds.to_json())

    # Build the Google Drive service
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Google Drive folder ID
    folder_id = myfolderID

    # Create the target directory if it doesn't exist
    target_dir = os.path.join(Path(__file__).resolve().parent, 'images')
    os.makedirs(target_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # List files in the specified folder
    response = service.files().list(q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and mimeType='image/jpeg'",
                                    fields='files(id, name)').execute()
    files = response.get('files', [])

    # Download each image
    image_sources = []
    for file in files:
        file_id = file['id']
        file_name = file['name']
        file_path = os.path.join(target_dir, file_name)
        # Check if the image already exists
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            # Download the image
            request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as fh:
                downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
                done = False
                while done is False:
                    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        image_sources.append(file_path)

    # Render the index.html template with the downloaded image sources
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'image_sources': image_sources})
```

I already added the URI to the Authorized redirect URIs in the Google Cloud Console. Tried in private mode, clean cache and run the project multiple times.

I added myself as Test user in the OAuth consent screen too.

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI198.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI198.png)